# how to use variables in the url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I have seen in android if userid is a variable then we use it like http://abc.com/user/"+userid+"/bookmarks to get web services of url.
how it can be done in iPhone to achieve the same thing.I have tried the above method as well as this http://abc.com/user/userid/bookmarks.bt not getting the anything.so,anyone can tell me how to do this.

Comment: which api are u using please give the api name so i can help u :)

Comment: json api i am using for web services..and try to get access token from facebook sdk..

Answer (score 1):

```
//Use thie code FBRequestWrapper.m 


- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    NSLog(@"Parsed Response: %@", result);

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishedPublishingPost:)])
        [self.delegate finishedPublishingPost:self];
}
```

Comment: k..once i am getting access token i have to pass it through the url to get Uid such as http://abc.com/fb_redirect_mobile/?accessToken=access token value.How can i do this.

Comment: I tried to put access token value in a variable and then access it from there bt its nt happening..

Comment: use the nsstring in appdelagate and save the access tokan in nsstring and use that string in yr url  :)

Comment: how to use that i have used like this abc.com/fb_redirect_mobile/?accessToken=accesstokenvalue.here accesstokenvalue is a variable..